# Question when drawing a graph in r(dodge or geom_line)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I want to express the frequency of each column (a,b,c,d,e) in a graph of (t) for each group.
I don't know what to do.
As shown in the figure, the data was selected in the form of a data frame, but I don't know what to do when I express it in the next graph.
I tried to extract only the value for a with ggplot, but even this didn't work out. Is there a good way?
Is there a way to express it with lines other than bar graphs?
Help me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(t = c("m", "i", "j", "z"),
                 a = c(300, 20, 15, 500),
                 b = c(100, 44, 99, 320),
                 c = c(200, 57, 98, 17),
                 d = c(150, 52, 122, 666),
                 e = c(50, 89, 64, 68))

library(tidyverse)
library(reshape)
df %>%
  melt(id.vars = "t") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = t, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If you apply it as melt, there is an error that the name does not match.
I'm not sure why.
For reference, I took out the value entered in the index with add_rownames.
ex) The values of t were the existing indexes. The column name t was given as rownames and taken out as a data value belonging to t (so the t column and its data value exist as shown in the figure).)

After that, I tried it your way, but the melt error occurs.

Thanks to you, I know how to do it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: No problem! Next time please share your data so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot the data longer to merge all counts of columns a to e inside just one name and value column, which can be used as dimension aesthetics for ggplot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~t, ~a, ~b,
  "m", 300, 100,
  "i", 20, 44,
  "j", 15, 99
)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(-t) %>%
  ggplot(aes(t, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thank,,,you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I solved it
I've never seen a function and a package before, but thanks to you, I know